# Using Drupal-7 and Google Maps API, How to find Distance and assign a tax rate based on the address?

Tags: google-maps, drupal-7

What I'm looking at being able to do is to be able to plug in an address in the Denver, CO area and have the system spit back at me several things:

1) The driving distance from my place of business to the address input

2) Tell me if it's in a certain city (Specifically Commerce City)

3) Allow me to assign a tax rate to certain areas and have that spit back out at me based on that address

Delivery tax rates are (in Colorado at least) based on where the material is being picked up, not where you purchase it.  So, if you pick up the material from our physical location, it's one tax rate, but if you have it delivered outside of Commerce City, it's a different tax rate.  So, what I'm trying to do is have the system toss at me the above information in separate line items.

I understand that you can place polygons on the Google Maps API, but I've been unable to figure that out, which will help me on the third point.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) The driving distance from my place of business to the address input

Since you'll only need 1 place (the other is your place of business), you can use [Google Maps Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro) to determine the driving distance.

> 2) Tell me if it's in a certain city (Specifically Commerce City)

[Place Details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) response (provided you already were able to retrieve the `placeId`) will have `address_components` that can have the city details. You can just match it to your data to determine if its part of a certain city.

> 3) Allow me to assign a tax rate to certain areas and have that spit back out at me based on that address

This may have to be implemented on your side. You'll have to set the tax rate of a city and another, just need to be matched with the address.

Hope this helps!